# get mac address of the client machine from python

Tags: java, python, macos, mac-address

Hi I am trying to capture the mac address of the client machine from python or java.I tried from java but no luck.its printing only for server mac address.I need client mac address.I tried some methods in python.

```
from uuid import getnode as get_mac
mac = get_mac()
```

The above code print uuid number of the machine.But I think it works only for server machine.I need to capture for client machine.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: There are two problems with your task. a) You can get the MAC address of machines in your local subnet only b) the lower layers of the OSI stack are not exposed to, the serving application by the OS. They could be retrieved from the ARP cache, but how differs on your OS.

Answer (score 1):

After a `pip install netifaces`:

```
import netifaces
print(netifaces.ifaddresses('wlan0')[netifaces.AF_LINK]['addr'])
```

Should print the mac address of your interface:
    ac:bc:32:ba:bd:cb

More info [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/netifaces)

Answer (score 0):

You can use system interfaces address file

```
def getmacaddress(interface):
    macaddress = open('/sys/class/net/'+interface+'/address').readline()
    return macaddress[0:17]
```

call this using `MACADDRESS = getmacaddress("wlan0")`
This will return your system macaddress.